# Getting events from specific calendar using office 365 API

Tags: office365, outlook-restapi

I am trying to get events from specific calendar (non default) using Office 365 API. I found this URL from the office 365 API docs.

```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/{version}/me/calendars/{calendar_id}/calendarview?startDateTime={start_datetime}&endDateTime={end_datetime}
```

Where i replaced {calendar_id} with actual ID which i got from another API call which returns all calendar groups.

```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/{version}/me/calendargroups
```

After replacing all relevant parameters, i am getting a HTTP 500 error.

But i can get events for my default calendar with

```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/{version}/me/calendarview?startDateTime={start_datetime}&endDateTime={end_datetime}
```

How can i get events from specific (non default) calendar ?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form you have is right. However, you said you got the ID from `GET https://outlook.office.com/api/{version}/me/calendargroups`, which doesn't return calendars, but calendar groups! So the ID you have is likely the issue. Try doing a `GET https://outlook.office.com/api/{version}/me/calendars` to get the actual calendar folders, then use the ID from the one you want to query.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason. It worked. you were right, i was using the Calendar groups id, which was wrong.

Comment: Just wondering, Is there a way to get events from all users calendars (default and others) in one call. I cannot find it, hence had to restore to other ways to get first other calendar ID and then get events of this calendar.

Comment: Can we set timezone while requesting events in range?

Answer (score 1):

How to get all events of a calendar with "recurence" expression?
Using

```
GET  https://outlook.office.com/api/{version}/me/calendars/{calendar_id}/calendarview?startDateTime={start_datetime}&endDateTime={end_datetime}
```

It returns me several events instead of one with the expression recurrence.