# Read secondary calendars using Office 365 REST API

Tags: php, rest, calendar, office365, office365api

Using Office 365 REST API I can easily read the main calendar of a given account. A simple example using PHP is given [here](https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/tutorial/php).

But how do I read the secondary calendars like "test" shown in the screenshot below? Events from secondary calendars don't show up in the API requests. Somehow it makes sense that I must tell the API which calendar I want to access (there could be many of them), but where or how in the API call do I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#get-series-master-and-single-events-rest):

> Get a collection of series master and single instance events from the
>   user's primary calendar (../me/events) **or from a different calendar**.
>
> GET
>   https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendars/{calendar_id}/events

where {calendar_id} is the ID of the calendar you wish to access.

You can find how to obtain the ID in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32203545/234466).

It works.